# sql - last value from a column and clock value

Tags: sql, mariadb, groupwise-maximum

i try to have for each host last value of name in showing last clock,

i tried :

```
SELECT distinct HOST , e.name, e.severity, FROM_UNIXTIME(e.clock), e.clock
     FROM hosts
     LEFT JOIN host_inventory ON (host_inventory.hostid = hosts.hostid)
     LEFT JOIN items i ON (i.hostid = hosts.hostid)
     LEFT JOIN functions f ON (f.itemid = i.itemid)
     INNER JOIN triggers t ON (t.triggerid = f.triggerid AND t.value=1)
     INNER JOIN events e ON (e.objectid = t.triggerid)
     ORDER BY e.clock desc
```

i have :

[image]

i want :

[image]

thanks for any response

Comment: please post your sample data/expected output as `text`

Comment: what's your DB version ?

Comment: Why the join to `host_inventory`? You are not using this table, it only leads to duplicate rows in your intermediate result.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [row_number()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/row_number/) to deduplicate:

```
WITH hosts_cte AS (
  SELECT HOST, 
         e.name, 
         e.severity, 
         FROM_UNIXTIME(e.clock) AS clock_date, 
         e.clock,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY HOST ORDER BY e.clock DESC) AS Rn
  FROM   hosts
  LEFT JOIN host_inventory
       ON host_inventory.hostid = hosts.hostid
  LEFT JOIN items i 
       ON i.hostid = hosts.hostid
  LEFT JOIN functions f 
       ON f.itemid = i.itemid
  INNER JOIN triggers t 
       ON t.triggerid = f.triggerid AND t.value=1
  INNER JOIN events e 
       ON e.objectid = t.triggerid
)

SELECT HOST, 
       name, 
       severity, 
       clock_date, 
       clock
FROM   hosts_cte
WHERE  Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an window analytic function such as `row_number()` provided your database version is at least `10.2` :

```
SELECT host, name, severity, clock_un, clock  
  FROM 
  (
    SELECT HOST, e.name, e.severity, FROM_UNIXTIME(e.clock) as clock_un, e.clock,
           row_number() over (partition by host order by e.clock) as rn
      FROM hosts h
      LEFT JOIN items i
        ON i.hostid = h.hostid
      LEFT JOIN functions f
        ON f.itemid = i.itemid
     INNER JOIN triggers t
        ON t.triggerid = f.triggerid AND t.value = 1
     INNER JOIN events e
        ON e.objectid = t.triggerid
  ) t
 WHERE rn = 1
 ORDER BY clock desc
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=bcaf3e4ecc1ba834f24f9924022d4376)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Notes:

- Your `INNER JOIN`s are undoing your `LEFT JOIN`s.
- You don't need `host_inventory`.

The answer to your question is then to use `ROW_NUMBER()`.  If you want all hosts -- even those with no such events -- I would suggest:

```
SELECT he.*
FROM (SELECT h.host , e.name, e.severity, FROM_UNIXTIME(e.clock), e.clock,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h.hostid ORDER BY e.clock DESC) as seqnum
      FROM hosts h LEFT JOIN
           items i
           ON i.hostid = hosts.hostid LEFT JOIN
           functions f
           ON f.itemid = i.itemid LEFT JOIN
           triggers t
           ON t.triggerid = f.triggerid AND
              t.value = 1 LEFT JOIN
           events e
           ON e.objectid = t.triggerid
     ) he
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

I am guessing that `host` comes from the `hosts` table.